# MySQL group and aggregate for several consecutive days

Tags: mysql

My table is designed to contain pets and their activity data, e.g, sleep time and exercise time. The table definition is provided below.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TEST_ACTIVITY(
   pet_id INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
   simple_sleep_time INT(11),
   deep_sleep_time INT(11),
   mild_movement_time INT(11),
   moderate_movement_time INT(11),
   severe_movement_time INT(11),
   start_time INT(11),
   date DATE,
   PRIMARY KEY (pet_id, start_time, date)
) ENGINE=INNODB
```

The following data is inserted to the table.

```
INSERT INTO TEST_ACTIVITY (pet_id, simple_sleep_time, deep_sleep_time,mild_movement_time, moderate_movement_time, severe_movement_time, start_time, date) 
VALUES 
(100,  1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, '2015-03-10'), 
(100,  2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 30, '2015-03-10'),  
(100,  3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, '2015-03-11'), 
(100,  4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 30, '2015-03-11'), 
(100,  5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, '2015-03-12'), 
(100,  6, 1, 1, 1, 1, 30, '2015-03-12'), 
(100,  7, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, '2015-03-13'), 
(100,  8, 1, 1, 1, 1, 30, '2015-03-13'),  
(101,  9, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, '2015-03-10'), 
(101,  10, 1, 1, 1, 1, 30, '2015-03-10'), 
(101,  11, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, '2015-03-11'), 
(101,  12, 1, 1, 1, 1, 30, '2015-03-11'),
(101,  13, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, '2015-03-12'),
(101,  14, 1, 1, 1, 1, 30, '2015-03-12'),
(101,  15, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, '2015-03-13'),
(101,  16, 1, 1, 1, 1, 30, '2015-03-13'),
(102,  17, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, '2015-03-10'),
(102,  18, 1, 1, 1, 1, 30, '2015-03-10'),
(102,  19, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, '2015-03-11'),
(102,  20, 1, 1, 1, 1, 30, '2015-03-11'),
(102,  21, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, '2015-03-12'),
(102,  22, 1, 1, 1, 1, 30, '2015-03-12'),
(102,  23, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, '2015-03-13'),
(102,  24, 1, 1, 1, 1, 30, '2015-03-13');

select * from TEST_ACTIVITY ORDER BY pet_id, date, start_time;

+--------+-------------------+-----------------+--------------------+------------------------+----------------------+------------+------------+
| pet_id | simple_sleep_time | deep_sleep_time | mild_movement_time | moderate_movement_time | severe_movement_time | start_time | date       |
+--------+-------------------+-----------------+--------------------+------------------------+----------------------+------------+------------+
|    100 |                 1 |               1 |                  1 |                      1 |                    1 |          0 | 2015-03-10 |
|    100 |                 2 |               1 |                  1 |                      1 |                    1 |         30 | 2015-03-10 |
|    100 |                 3 |               1 |                  1 |                      1 |                    1 |          0 | 2015-03-11 |
|    100 |                 4 |               1 |                  1 |                      1 |                    1 |         30 | 2015-03-11 |
|    100 |                 5 |               1 |                  1 |                      1 |                    1 |          0 | 2015-03-12 |
|    100 |                 6 |               1 |                  1 |                      1 |                    1 |         30 | 2015-03-12 |
|    100 |                 7 |               1 |                  1 |                      1 |                    1 |          0 | 2015-03-13 |
|    100 |                 8 |               1 |                  1 |                      1 |                    1 |         30 | 2015-03-13 |
|    101 |                 9 |               1 |                  1 |                      1 |                    1 |          0 | 2015-03-10 |
|    101 |                10 |               1 |                  1 |                      1 |                    1 |         30 | 2015-03-10 |
|    101 |                11 |               1 |                  1 |                      1 |                    1 |          0 | 2015-03-11 |
|    101 |                12 |               1 |                  1 |                      1 |                    1 |         30 | 2015-03-11 |
|    101 |                13 |               1 |                  1 |                      1 |                    1 |          0 | 2015-03-12 |
|    101 |                14 |               1 |                  1 |                      1 |                    1 |         30 | 2015-03-12 |
|    101 |                15 |               1 |                  1 |                      1 |                    1 |          0 | 2015-03-13 |
|    101 |                16 |               1 |                  1 |                      1 |                    1 |         30 | 2015-03-13 |
|    102 |                17 |               1 |                  1 |                      1 |                    1 |          0 | 2015-03-10 |
|    102 |                18 |               1 |                  1 |                      1 |                    1 |         30 | 2015-03-10 |
|    102 |                19 |               1 |                  1 |                      1 |                    1 |          0 | 2015-03-11 |
|    102 |                20 |               1 |                  1 |                      1 |                    1 |         30 | 2015-03-11 |
|    102 |                21 |               1 |                  1 |                      1 |                    1 |          0 | 2015-03-12 |
|    102 |                22 |               1 |                  1 |                      1 |                    1 |         30 | 2015-03-12 |
|    102 |                23 |               1 |                  1 |                      1 |                    1 |          0 | 2015-03-13 |
|    102 |                24 |               1 |                  1 |                      1 |                    1 |         30 | 2015-03-13 |
+--------+-------------------+-----------------+--------------------+------------------------+----------------------+------------+------------+
```

I want to first calculate each pet's daily score using this formula: `score = SUM(severe_movement_time) + SUM(moderate_movement_time) + SUM(mild_movement_time) + SUM(simple_sleep_time)`, and then decide each pet's rank based on its score. By using the following query, I can do it for one day, 2015-03-10.

```
SELECT pet_id, date, score, rank 
FROM 
(
SELECT t.pet_id, t.date, t.score, @prev := @curr, @curr := score, @rank := IF(@prev = @curr, @rank, @rank+1) AS rank 
FROM (
    SELECT pet_id, date, COALESCE(SUM(simple_sleep_time), 0) shallow, 
           COALESCE(SUM(deep_sleep_time), 0) deep, COALESCE(SUM(mild_movement_time), 0) light, 
           COALESCE(SUM(moderate_movement_time), 0) moderate, COALESCE(SUM(severe_movement_time), 0) heavy, 
          (COALESCE(SUM(severe_movement_time), 0) + COALESCE(SUM(moderate_movement_time), 0) + COALESCE(SUM(mild_movement_time), 0) + COALESCE(SUM(simple_sleep_time), 0)) score 
    FROM TEST_ACTIVITY  
    WHERE date = DATE('2015-03-10')
    GROUP BY pet_id 
    ORDER BY score DESC
) t, (SELECT @curr := null, @prev := null, @rank := 0) r ORDER BY score DESC
) x
```

My question is how to write a single query to calculate the scores and rankings for several consecutive days, for example, 4 days (start_date=2015-03-10, end_date=2015-03-13). The expected result is listed below.

```
| pet_id | date       | score | rank |
+--------+------------+-------+------+
|    102 | 2015-03-10 | 41    |    1 |
|    101 | 2015-03-10 | 25    |    2 |
|    100 | 2015-03-10 | 9     |    3 |
|    102 | 2015-03-11 | 45    |    1 |
|    101 | 2015-03-11 | 29    |    2 |
|    100 | 2015-03-11 | 13    |    3 |
|    102 | 2015-03-12 | 49    |    1 |
|    101 | 2015-03-12 | 33    |    2 |
|    100 | 2015-03-12 | 17    |    3 |
|    102 | 2015-03-13 | 53    |    1 |
|    101 | 2015-03-13 | 37    |    2 |
|    100 | 2015-03-13 | 21    |    3 |
```

Comment: Seriously consider revising your design

Comment: just group by GROUP BY pet_id, date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following...

```
SELECT pet_id,
       date,
       score,
       rank 
FROM 
(
    SELECT pet_id,
           date,
           score,
           @prevDate := COALESCE( @currDate,
                                  CURDATE() ) as prevDate,
           @currDate := date,
           @prevScore := COALESCE( @currScore,
                                   -1 ) AS prevScore,
           @currScore := score,
           @rank := IF( @prevDate <> @currDate,
                        1,
                        IF( @prevScore = @currScore,
                            @rank,
                            @rank + 1 ) ) AS rank
    FROM
    (
        SELECT pet_id,
               date,
               ( COALESCE( SUM( severe_movement_time ),
                           0 ) +
                     COALESCE( SUM( moderate_movement_time ),
                               0 ) +
                     COALESCE( SUM( mild_movement_time ),
                               0 ) +
                     COALESCE( SUM( simple_sleep_time ),
                               0 ) ) AS score
        FROM TEST_ACTIVITY  
        WHERE date BETWEEN DATE( '2015-03-10' ) AND DATE( '2015-03-13' )
        GROUP BY pet_id,
                 date
    ) AS scoreFinder, ( SELECT @currDate := NULL,
                               @prevDate := NULL,
                               @currScore := NULL,
                               @prevScore := NULL,
                               @rank := 0 ) AS r
    ORDER BY date,
             score DESC
) AS rankFinder;
```

I based my Answer on the code that you gave us.  My first modification was to remove the calculations of `shallow`, `deep`, etc., as these are never referenced again after their calculation.

My next modification was to change the inner-most query's `WHERE` clause to use the `BETWEEN` operator to define the date range that records to be considered must come from.  I have used the explicit values from your Question, but you can of course use other values or variables holding those values.

Since we are interested in each `pet_id`'s `score` for each `date`, I expanded this lists grouping clause to `GROUP BY` `pet_id` and `date` pairings.

Since no sorting of the list is needed at this point I removed the `ORDER BY` clause.

I dislike ultrashort aliases as the more complex a statement the easier it is to lose track of what they represent and make mistakes, either when coding or debugging, which is why I changed `t` to `scoreFinder` (I try to use short but descriptive aliases).  You are of course free to call it pretty much whatever you like.

This list joined with `valuesInitialiser` forms the basis of the middle-most query, which starts by ordering this base by `date`, and subsorting on score.

With a sorted list now available computation of the `rank` can begin.  Since a record's `rank` is dependent on both its `date` and its `score` in comparison to those of the previous record, the current and previous values of each must be tracked.  As the more dominant field in the sorting, the values for `date` will need to be compared first.  If they are different then the first record of a new `date` is being examined, which means that the value of `rank` will need to be (re)initialised to `1`.  If the two dates are the same, then a change in `score` will need to be tested.  If the score has not changed then the current value of `rank` will need to be used.  Otherwise the current value of `rank` will need to be incremented and the new value used.

With the values of `rank` generated, all that remains is to select just the desired fields.

To test this statement I ran it against your supplied data, which produced the desired results.  However, I noticed that the `score`s from the sample data were all different, so I changed one of the records from `( 101,  12, 1, 1, 1, 1, 30, '2015-03-11' )` to `( 101,  12, 1, 1, 1, 17, 30, '2015-03-11' )` so that the `score` for that `pet_id` and that `date` matched that for `pet_id = 102` for that `date`.  I than retested my statement, which as hoped produced the same rank for both `pet_id`'s.

If you have any questions or comments, then please feel free to post a Comment accordingly.

Comment: Pressing Enter or copying in a new line character tends to finish a Comment at that point.

Comment: Do you want the rresults sorted by `date` and subsorted by `score`, then?

Comment: Hi toonice, the rankings are incorrect. For example, when pet_id=100, date=2015-03-10, and score=9, rank is equal to 2 (which should be 3). A pet's rank is based on its daily score. For example, on date=2015-03-10, pet_id=102 has highest score 41, its rank is 1.

Comment: That's right. I want the results sorted by date and subsorted by score. Thanks.

Comment: Answer updated.  I will finish the explanation when I get back from dinner.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141714/discussion-between-kingsford-black-and-toonice).

Comment: Thank you for accepting my Answer.  Please note that I have updated my code to make it very slightly more efficient and that I have added my explanation.  Again, if you have any questions or comments, then please feel free to post a Comment accordingly.